# How do I troubleshoot not being able to connect to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, centos

For years a Linux VM running MySQL has worked like a champ.  This is a machine that is used for testing website changes before they get pushed to the real live site.  Our live site is hosted by a hosting company comes with great support but our dev site is hosted and maintained in our office by a noob (me) who barely knows any Linux etc.

The other day when I went to test out some changes to the site on the dev machine I noticed it couldn't connect to the database.  I would just restore from backup but of course I never implemented a backup process because I didn't think I would need it since it is just a dev box.  So now I either have to fix MySQL or start the dev site again from scratch which took me a while to get right last time.

So every page on our site (php) starts with a line that includes/runs code to connect to the database.  That is how I first noticed the issue because every page looked messed up and going in to page source in the browser and at the top of every page is "MySQL login was bad." before the `<html>` tag.  I tried restarting the server and it does the same thing.  I did a "ps aux | less" and found:

```
/usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-external-locking --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

That tells me it is running.  I can't use the MySQL workbench to connect either.  Why would a Linux machine, that noone else in the organization will touch, out of the blue stop allowing MySQL connections?  The MySQL standard port is open on our firewall, but we use an original user name with a strong password so I would assume it was safe.

Comment: Has the server run out of space? Check the mysql logs to see any errors.

Comment: can you connect from the command line on the same server? run `df -h` to see if there's free space available

Comment: Try rebooting the VM, or if you can, the VM host.

Comment: @halfer that would be a windows solution. No need to reboot anything here. actually, better not reboot, because if the server was hacked a reboot could create new issues and evidence could get lost.

Comment: Clone the VM drive whilst it is still running, then reboot - unless you think something might still be hanging on in RAM? Have you any reason to suspect a hack?

Comment: I believe the issue is running out of space.  I am expanding the drive size right now to see if that fix it.  It seemed illogical to me that changing a few content pages and updating videos would break the ability to connect to databases, but it never crossed my mind that I could have run out of space or that it would cause it to prevent connecting.  I will know in about an hour.

Answer (score 0):

If possibly, try to mysql connect from the commandline as root.  If the root user is defined in mysql, then you might need a password, but without a password set, I think you can just log in as root and then grant permissions from the interactive mysql session.  This is what it looks like below, there is also a process to reset the passwords, I can do it for you if it seems too risky:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

```
  root@grapevine:~# mysql
  Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
  Your MySQL connection id is 105
  Server version: 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

  Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

  Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
  affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
  owners.

  Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

  mysql> show databases;
  +---------------------+
  | Database            |
  +---------------------+
  | information_schema  |
  | dolibarr            |
  | drupal7             |
  | mysql               |
  | performance_schema  |
  | secretbe_drupalmain |
  +---------------------+
  6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

  mysql>
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to acclimatise the OP to accepting help from strangers that requires them to divulge access credentials. Also, answers here are for all future readers, not just the OP - and I don't imagine you are offering to help anyone who reads this `:-)`

Comment: "try to mysql connect from the commandline as root" What's the point? MySQL dosn't care about the user who calls it - it just takes it as default username. So you can as well do `mysql -u root` as normal user and achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

On the  mysql-server check if something is listening on that port :

```
netstat -tlpn  | grep 3306
```

(3306 is the default port, but you can check if you use another port: `grep port /etc/mysql/my.cnf` )

If this works try, to connect locally on that mysql machine.

```
mysql -u username -p --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306
```

(it should ask for the password now.)

If you are logged in, do this to check the current mysql connections:

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected'
```

It should return some value. The database has a connection limit; if your applications do not close connections correctly that could be the reason why you cant set up a new connection.

Now check if the port is accessible from the VM, a quick way is this trick:
`curl -I 192.168.1.100:3306` (replace the ip with your database IP). It should return some weird error-message containing '...../_o3mysql_native_password' .  at least you know now mysql is behind that port and you have access.